# How to remove the existing spark environment and related packages from computer?

Tags: apache-spark, ubuntu, pyspark

I had installed spark using the below method to my ubuntu 20.04.3 system. As there are certain dependency issues, im looking for a way to completely remove this environment of spark. But im not able to find the proper way.

Here's the link which has the exact steps that i used to install spark. https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-spark-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

All spark libraries are found by env var `SPARK_HOME`. You can remove everything from this path.